# Correlations in count data with many zeros

Tags: correlation, count-data, zero-inflation

I have two count data variables X and Y that contain many zero values (90% in X, 60% in Y). I would like to check if a correlation exists between these variables, but I'm not sure how to proceed due to presence of zero values.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try with a non-parametric correlation measure, like Spearman or Kendall correlations. This approach is more appropriate than using standard Pearson correlation.

Comment: When should I use Spearman or Kendall correlations?